# Using xarray how do I replace all values in a Dataset with values from another matching Dataset that have matching subset of coordinates?

Tags: python-xarray

I have a dataset with old data (orig) and a new dataset i have generated with a new subset of values that I want to replace in the old dataset which have matching coordinates (replace).

I have tried various combinations of concat, merge, update and combine_first and so far have been unable to achieve the goal. Note I cant just iterate over replace and index into orig either as in reality these are large xarrays using dask in the backend.

Some example code is below:

```
import xarray
import numpy

orig = xarray.Dataset({
    'depth':       (['position'], numpy.zeros(50, dtype=numpy.int32)),
    'depth_count': (['position'], numpy.zeros(50, dtype=numpy.int32)),
}, coords={'position': (['position'], numpy.arange(1000, 1000+50, dtype=numpy.uint32))})

replace = xarray.Dataset({
    'depth':       (['position'], numpy.array([-1, -2], dtype=numpy.int32)),
    'depth_count': (['position'], numpy.array([-1, -2], dtype=numpy.int32)),
}, coords={'position': (['position'], numpy.array([1000, 1003], dtype=numpy.uint32))})

# According to: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/combining.html really should be using concat()
# Makes array bigger instead of replaces items, tried various diff params of concat
print (str(xarray.concat([replace, orig], dim='position')))
```

This produces the output:

```
<xarray.Dataset> Dimensions:      (position: 52) Coordinates:   *
position     (position) uint64 1000 1003 1000 1001 ... 1046 1047 1048
1049 Data variables:
    depth        (position) int32 -1 -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    depth_count  (position) int32 -1 -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The output I want to achieve is:

```
<xarray.Dataset> Dimensions:      (position: 50) Coordinates:   *
position     (position) uint64 1000 1001 1002 1003 ... 1046 1047 1048
1049 Data variables:
    depth        (position) int32 -1 0 0 -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    depth_count  (position) int32 -1 0 0 -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: If you're really replacing all the data, what about just broadcasting replace against orig to reshape it to the new shape? `new = replace.broadcast_like(orig)` should reshape the data to include all of orig's dimensions.

Comment: Thanks that works, if I do: `correct = replace.broadcast_like(orig).combine_first(orig)`

Comment: I'm confused - what about orig do you want to see in the result other than the shape?

Comment: Sorry for all the edits. Not used to SO. I basically want to update a subset of the data in "orig" to new values. The new values are defined in "replace". Using the line above actually resolves the issue by matching the shape filling empty spaces with nan, so when using combine the nan's which are the data points in orig I want to keep are replaced. Actually looking `replace.combine_first(orig)` works as it is alone

Comment: I see! Didn't realize you were trying to fill NaNs. And no worries :) it takes a bit of getting used to. It helps to cut down your question to the minimal amount necessary to convey the problem, but you do have to balance that with giving enough context to see broader issues when the solution is actually approaching the problem in a different way. Tough balance! Hope this helped.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and mark it answered if that fixed the issue for you!

Comment: `replace.combine_first(orig)` alone seems to do the trick, no need to explicitly call `broadcast_like`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Michael in the comments.

Using: replace.combine_first(orig) achieves the correct result as the items that exist in "orig" but are missing in "replace" when it is broadcast are filled with NaN's. Thus when combine first it will take the item defined in replace, and if non exists will then take the item in orig.

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.combine_first.html

Below is the code doing what I require:

```
import xarray
import numpy

orig = xarray.Dataset({
    'depth':       (['position'], numpy.zeros(50, dtype=numpy.int32)),
    'depth_count': (['position'], numpy.zeros(50, dtype=numpy.int32)),
}, coords={'position': (['position'], numpy.arange(1000, 1000+50, dtype=numpy.uint32))})

replace = xarray.Dataset({
    'depth':       (['position'], numpy.array([-1, -2], dtype=numpy.int32)),
    'depth_count': (['position'], numpy.array([-1, -2], dtype=numpy.int32)),
}, coords={'position': (['position'], numpy.array([1000, 1003], dtype=numpy.uint32))})

print (str(replace.combine_first(orig)))
```

This results in output:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (position: 50)
Coordinates:
  * position     (position) uint64 1000 1001 1002 1003 ... 1046 1047 1048 1049
Data variables:
    depth        (position) float64 -1.0 0.0 0.0 -2.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    depth_count  (position) float64 -1.0 0.0 0.0 -2.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```